# How to inform the users of an Android app that a new version is available in the Google Play Store through Notification

Tags: android, google-play

I lately saw an app notifying me (through Android notification) that a new version of the app is available in the Google Play Store and then I had to go there and update it manually by clicking the Update button. This happened even though I had Auto-update enabled for that specific app and auto-updates were enabled for the Google Play Store as a whole.

I would like to duplicate this behaviour for our own app. We have an app that should be updated manually rather automatically. The app should notify the user that a new update is available but then force the user to click the Update button in the Google Play Store when he or she is ready for the update.

How to enable this behaviour in the Google Play Store? I could not find so much about this thing in the Google Play Developer Console. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use the In App Update API.

You can find out how to implement it here in Google's documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates